# how to take value in composite record type in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

> ERROR at line 4: ORA-06550: line 4, column 5: PLS-00320: the
>   declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: line 4,
>   column 1: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
>   incomplete or malformed ORA-06550: line 10, column 10: PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier ORA-06550: line 9, column 1: PL/SQL:
>   SQL Statement ignored

```
declare 
type emp_detp_record is record 
( 
emp emp%rowtype,
dept dept%rowtype
);
emp_dept emp_detp_record;
begin 
select * into 
emp_dept 
from emp,dept
where emp.deptno =dept.deptno 
and empno =7839;
end;
/
```

Comment: I don't think that's supported. I set up a test and aliased the tables so I could put each one specifically where it needs to go, but it gave me a different error: PLS-00494: coercion into multiple record targets not supported. I'll keep playing with it, but I hope someone that knows more about this will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use collections to handle such scenarios. Hope this might help you.

```
declare 
cursor emp_dept_cur is
select emp.empno,dept.deptno 
from emp,dept
where emp.deptno =dept.deptno 
and empno =7839;
type emp_detp_record is table of emp_dept_cur%rowtype;
emp_dept emp_detp_record;
begin 
open emp_dept_cur;
loop
fetch emp_dept_cur bulk collect into emp_dept;
exit when emp_dept.count=0;
null;
end loop;
close emp_dept_cur;
end;
/
```

Comment: I know this was the accepted answer, but it doesn't really answer the question if you can have composite record types without having to specify all the fields. If we were going to specify all the fields, we could just use the same method that was in the original question.

Comment: @Bob - not sure what you mean, but if you think "select \*" is the problem, it isn't. The join is calculated, and then the data is fetched from it; at that point, there's no "memory" of the rows resulting from a join, and not from a single table.

Comment: @Bob: By creating the record types like this are tend to cause PLS-00597 as the query will provide a result set. I've faced this issue in the past hence started using collections ever since.

Comment: @mathguy Let me clarify. In the example from the OP, he was trying to join two rowtypes into one. As I stated in my comment on his post, I don't think that can be done. The solution that was used here doesn't net the same result as what was attempted in the code from the OP. Your post is the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Bob - If by "my solution" you mean the one here, it is not mine. I didn't read this solution, I don't know or care if it works or not. My point was that the OP's original error wasn't trying to join two types into one; rather, it was that he was trying to DIS-join something that was already joined and "fetch" it into two rowtype variables. THAT is what doesn't work.

Comment: @mathguy I was referring to your actual post where you that "That is not possible." I am agreeing with you, once they are joined, you have a single record type, so you can't do what was trying do, at least not the way he was trying to do it. This answer here (not yours) doesn't directly solve what it looks like the OP was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CURSOR` and anchor the record to the cursor's `ROWTYPE`:

```
declare 
  cursor emp_dept_cur is
    select * 
    from emp 
    join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno;
  emp_dept_rec emp_dept_cur%rowtype;
begin 
  select * into 
    emp_dept_rec
  from emp 
  join dept on emp.deptno =dept.deptno 
  where empno = 7839;
 -- dbms_output.put_line(emp_dept_rec.deptno); -- raises PLS-00302: component 'deptno' must be declared
end;
```

Some notes:

- please don't use the old Oracle syntax for JOINs (multiple tables in the FROM clause). Use ANSI JOINs instead
- this will cause problems with duplicate column names. In your example, you have two columns named `deptno` - one from emp and one from dept. This will raise an error as soon as you try to access it (see commented line in my code)

Comment: I believe you can solve the column name issue by joining with the USING keyword. I totally agree with the old JOIN syntax, but I understand why some people still use it. My company insists that we use the Oracle syntax, which I have fought to change, but lost that battle even after presenting an official document from Oracle containing a list of reasons you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code... The error at line 4 is caused by the name you chose for your attribute; change `emp` to `x`, and `dept` to `y` in line 5, and the declaration will work.

Then in the body of your procedure you fetch data from a row set. The fact that the row set is created by joining two tables is irrelevant; first the join is computed, and then you extract rows from it and try to separate the values into `emp` and `dept` subrows. That is not possible; when the data comes in from the join, the fact it is a join and not a single table is "water under the bridge." If you really want or need to keep the data from `emp` and from `dept` in separate attributes you should bring it in from `emp` and from `dept` separately.